# Global view multi website Magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, theme, price, quantity, websites

I have created multi website in magento.

I have few questions.

1 : My client want same product in both website with same sku but different with  price and quantity. I have checked product in website view the scope of price and quantity is set to Global, how do i change same product price and quantity in multi website.

2 : I have setup onestepcheckout extension. My client want onestepcheckout in one website view and in other website they want one page checkout. I checked onestepcheckout extension in website view it scope is set to global i can't disable this extension in one website view.

3 : If I setup multi theme for multi website. In time of installing new extension , should extension files go to both theme or in base folder.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sorry i don't know this. How to do it for quantity(stock)

Comment: You can change any product attribute (in the attributes screen)  from Global to Store View. You will then be able to change them per store view

Comment: I have checked 'qty' attribute in manage attribute section. It is not available

Answer (score 2):

1. You can set the price scope under System>Catalog>Price>Catalog Price Scope to Website Scope as Serpyre mentioned.

   A multi stock is not supported by Magento, therefore the stock is always global. But is is prepared to be implemented, so an extension can do the work. There are several extensions providing this feature on the market.
2. You can enable/disable the checkout types on store view scope under System>Sales>Checkout. If the extension has a global setting in this place, you could try to overwrite this.
3. For an extension you should always provide templates in base/default, so that the extension works in every theme. In addition you can then create templates for the different themes if necessary.